# STL function to test whether a value is within some range?

Tags: c++, stl

I have a function: `bool inBounds(int value, int low, int high)`. Is there an STL equivalent that does useful things (takes variables of different types, specifically)? I can't find one using Google, and I'd prefer to re-use rather than re-write.

Comment: Might I suggest `within` as a simpler name?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In C++17, there's no direct equivalent of a function like this, but for smaller types with fast equality comparisons you could use [`std::clamp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp):

```
if (val == std::clamp(val, low, high)) {
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can just write your own function to test for this:

```
template <typename T>
    bool IsInBounds(const T& value, const T& low, const T& high) {
    return !(value < low) && (value < high);
}
```

This checks if `value` is in the range [low, high).  If you want the range [low, high], you'd write this as

```
template <typename T>
    bool IsInBounds(const T& value, const T& low, const T& high) {
    return !(value < low) && !(high < value);
}
```

Note how this is defined purely in terms of `operator <`, which means that any class that supports just `operator <` can be used here.

Similarly, here's one using custom comparators:

```
template <typename T, typename R, typename Comparator>
    bool IsInBounds(const T& value, const R& low, const R& high, Comparator comp) {
    return !comp(value, low) && comp(value, high);
}
```

This latter one has the nice advantage that `low` and `high` don't have to be the same type as `value`, and as long as the comparator can handle that it will work just fine.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I'm still tentative with templates - the examples are muchly appreciated.

Comment: Is the inclusive lower / exclusive upper bound intentional?

Comment: @tzaman- I just assumed that's what was intended.  I'll post an update if different bounds are desired.

Comment: @tzaman Inclusive lower, exclusive upper is what I'm using at the moment.

Comment: Isn't std::clamp a C++17 feature?
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp

Comment: Thoughts on the speed of using `std::clamp` vs. `low < val && val < high`?

Answer (score 6):

```
bool inBounds(int value, int low, int high)
```

has the slight drawback that you have to remember which parameter goes where.
I can't be the only one whose perfectly rational parameter ordering is bewildering when returning to code after some time.

You could go the extra mile and define

```
template<typename T>
class Interval
{
public:
    Interval(T lo, T hi) : low(lo), high(hi) {}
    bool contains(T value) const { return low <= value && value < high; }
private:
    T low;
    T high;
};
template<typename T>
Interval<T> interval(T lo, T hi) { return Interval<T>(lo, hi); }
```

Then you can be more explicit about what you mean:

```
if (interval(a, b).contains(value))
    // ...
```

If one is in abstraction mode it's not too hard to generalise to accomodate different inclusive/exclusive combinations.

Of course this might be overkill for your purposes.
 YMMV, and all that.

Answer (score 1):

You could compose one from `std::less`, `std::more`, `std::bind` and `std::compose`, but that's truly overkill.

Lambda's are far easier:

`[](int value, int low, int high){return !(value < low) && (value < high);}`

or, if low and high are in scope

`[low, high](int value){return !(value < low) && (value < high)};`

Answer (score -2):

I'd almost think you'd be better off not attempt such a seemingly trivial task with a whole function and just inline the behavior.

Something like this:

```
int main()
{
    int value = 5;
    int lower = 0;
    int upper = 10;

    bool inside = lower < value && value < upper;

    std::cout << "inside: " << inside;
}
```

If you have a reason for not writing the code simply like this, please let me know and I can provide a more sophisticated answer.

Comment: You need to fix line 8: `lower < value < upper` doesn't work correctly in C++.  You'd have to split it into `lower < value && upper < value`.  I also disagree that this should be inlined.  It's a nice clean subroutine, and with compilers the way they are now it will almost certainly be inlined.

Comment: It's not a about performance in my case, I just have a hard time justifying abstracting this away with the presently available information.

Comment: I'm currently using it to bounds-check 4 values, which comes out to a rather large `if` statement - it's much easier to read if I wrap the test into a function, and there's less chance of me typographically failing.

Comment: Seems reasonable to me, the other response about STL should serve you well then. If it doesn't, describe what you need.

Comment: So your answer here seems to be to not answer the question at all? Its a really common thing, having a function for it is very handy.